# Compiler throws warning when trying to get a reference to a composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an issue whereby returning a reference to the composable function is interpreted as invoking the composable function resulting in the compiler throwing the following warning message:  **Functions which invoke @Composable functions must be marked with the @Composable annotation**. I understand that composable functions can only be invoked inside functions with composable context, however in this case I am just trying to get a reference to the function and not invoking it.   In the code snippet below, `content.value` throws the warning message. Any ideas of how to fix this ?

```
private typealias ComposableUnitLambda = @Composable() () -> Unit
private val EmptyRoute: ComposableUnitLambda = {}

@Model
class ContentHolder(var value: ComposableUnitLambda = EmptyRoute)

@Navigator.Name("compose")
class ComposableNavigator : Navigator<Destination>() { 
     val current: ComposableUnitLambda
           get() = content.value
 }
```